# Keys that sometimes exist on a typescript object depending on parameters

Tags: typescript

I have an object that takes a lot of time to construct fully (because it requires querying multiple database tables), so clients of that object specify which parts they need.  For instance, let's say that there's a User object that sometimes has Purchases and sometimes has Friends.  Right now, I'm using optional properties for that:

```
interface User {
  id: number
  purchases?: Purchase[]
  friends?: Friend[]
  friendsOfFriends?: Friend[]
}
```

And clients of a User could say `getUser(['purchases'])` to get a user where the `purchases` key is defined.

However, that means that any time I use `purchases`, `friends`, or `friendsOfFriends`, I need to tell typescript that the type is there (e.g., `user.purchases![0]` or `user.purchases && user.purchases[0]`), which is a little annoying.

Is there some way to tell Typescript that the passed in parameter determines which keys are present on the returned value?  E.g.:

- `getUser([])` returns an `{id: number}`
- `getUser(['purchases'])` returns an `{id: number; purchases: Purchase[]}`
- `getUser(['network'])` returns an `{id: number; friends: Friend[]; friendsOfFriends: Friend[]}` -- note that `network` gets us `friends` and `friendsOfFriends`
- `getUser(['purchases', 'network'])` returns an `{id: number; purchases: Purchase[]; friends: Friend[]; friendsOfFriends: Friend[]}`

In the real case, there are more than 2 possible keys to include, and I don't want to make combinatorially many overloaded types.

Is this possible in Typescript?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the special object pattern for this. If there are no purchases, for example, an empty array would be a good default. Would be a better design.

Comment: When I search for "special object pattern", I'm not able to find anything.  Could you link to something describing the special object pattern?

Comment: Uncle Bob talks a lot about it in clean code. However, all it really means is if a value isn't present rather than null or undefined use a substitute object with the same interface that can respond to all the same request, but either return the identity value for getters (like 0 for a tax amount getter or something) or not effect the system at large for things that generally have side effects.

In this case, just slot in an empty array instead if undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to leave the implementation of `getUser()` us you, as well as convincing the compiler that your implementation meets the type definition.  That is, I'm acting like `getUser()` is out in pure JavaScript land, and I'm just coming up with its type declaration so that the compiler can correctly handle calls to it.

First, the compiler needs some way of knowing about the mapping between arguments to `getUser()` and which sets of `User` keys they pick out.  Something like this, given your example:

```
interface KeyMap {
    purchases: "purchases",
    network: "friends" | "friendsOfFriends"
}
```

Armed with that, we need to tell the compiler how to calculate `UserType<K>` for some set of keys `K` from `KeyMap`.  Here's one way to do it:

```
type UserType<K extends keyof KeyMap> =
    User & Pick<Required<User>, KeyMap[K]> extends 
    infer O ? { [P in keyof O]: O[P] } : never;
```

The important bit is `User & Pick<Required<User>, KeyMap[K]>`:  The result is always going to be a `User` so we include that in an [intersection](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types).  We also take `KeyMap[K]`, the `User` keys pointed out by `K`, and [`Pick`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktk) these properties from `Required<User>`.  The [`Required<T>`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredt) type makes all optional keys into required ones.

The next bit that starts `extends infer O...` is really just using a [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) trick to take the ugly type `User & Pick...` and convert it into a single object type with spelled out properties.  If you prefer to see `User & Pick<Required<User>, "purchases">` instead of the object types below, you can remove everything starting with `extends` there.

Finally, the `getUser()` function typing looks like this:

```
declare function getUser<K extends keyof KeyMap>(keys: K[]): UserType<K>;
```

It takes an array of `KeyMap` keys and returns `UserType<K>` for those keys.

---

Let's make sure it works, using your example calls:

```
const user = getUser([]);
/* const user: {
    id: number;
    purchases?: Purchase[] | undefined;
    friends?: Friend[] | undefined;
    friendsOfFriends?: Friend[] | undefined;
} */

const userWithPurchases = getUser(['purchases']);
/* const userWithPurchases: {
    id: number;
    purchases: Purchase[];
    friends?: Friend[] | undefined;
    friendsOfFriends?: Friend[] | undefined;
} */

const userWithNetwork = getUser(['network']);
/* const userWithNetwork: {
    id: number;
    purchases?: Purchase[] | undefined;
    friends: Friend[];
    friendsOfFriends: Friend[];
} */

const userWithEverything = getUser(['purchases', 'network']);
/* const userWithEverything: {
    id: number;
    purchases: Purchase[];
    friends: Friend[];
    friendsOfFriends: Friend[];
} */
```

Those types look right to me.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.7.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoFcoIBZwM4oDeAsAFDIXJjagDmAXMnmFHQNxkC+ZoksiKAGKsIIACbIS5SmPQBbAEbRGIeUqgdS3Uj3DR4SZAFUCUSWUrJgYlWugXKAB0w58EPAH5GGLLgIBtAF0HChgRcU9GYWBRMSCQ5DCYiIB5GGjYyOQM8XitMl0+AxQAaQgATwBZOEdzaQpnXzc8RgAiRtcCPFaAGgSQCDAAdwB7KABrNqTM1uQAH2RW6dT08LFurjIwcscUE2gAFR2IAB4S5AgAD0gI5HGKkZhkMqqagD5kAF4E-bMAMjQwAQ4xOACUIABHdDAKAQMQnX5vHrPCrVRz+EqBD5XG7rKwgGDQZApZAeSTIfyofF3B5PFKBRgpSmBZCcZAqCAAN2gmjEEAQABs4LDEugQAgwMARiBkLRBr8zhdrpkaeVHijXo43gAKe7lFrPIIASkYvyOuzOb00BVICGlzGQ6FMX1l8tM2uNmgA9AAqZB2kAOp3KOqWay2RQ8hIdPzuLxoFyxoLzR3iCAwUBwzSWZbreM5OIshZivkZgZibOUXN4NIFrIF5PFtNlrNcZA+r02gNB0wAdWA1B8nXcLrlYF+HoA5DHmpPAkbvX7u2BHX2B9gh7GDVIwzZkKpIxpo4nmt4TwFApXQmt62tG6nS5mKwlq7Wb-m70WH+mn5o2R2u3tFdgygftqAAOUGUYJlHN1oCnAZhjGcY5wXMhfX9IDV2gMDsEgpCJkYHdKHDfc7CPepkBnLp403Nx7xLH9yyvRIbyiT8WNfVZknWdieKCP9207HRbSwkDcIAUW5KBymoOhYPHd1-Gnc93EnZFJ0Q6CUPnRdMMDYC12oKToFkmgQAYUMSL3A91BY6j3DPJoL04tjsg4l8bzfHiDQbS82wA8ggA)

---

Well, looking over your example again, you didn't have the optional properties included in the output as optional; they were just omitted.  If you really want to see that match your types exactly it's a bit more involved:

```
type RequiredKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: {} extends Pick<T, K> ? never : K }[keyof T];

type UserType<K extends keyof KeyMap> =
    Pick<User, RequiredKeys<User>> & Pick<Required<User>, KeyMap[K]> extends
    infer O ? { [P in keyof O]: O[P] } : never;

declare function getUser<K extends keyof KeyMap>(keys: K[]): UserType<K>;


const user = getUser([]);
/* const user: {
    id: number;
} */

const userWithPurchases = getUser(['purchases']);
/* const userWithPurchases: {
    id: number;
    purchases: Purchase[];
} */

const userWithNetwork = getUser(['network']);
/* const userWithNetwork: {
    id: number;
    friends: Friend[];
    friendsOfFriends: Friend[];
} */

const userWithEverything = getUser(['purchases', 'network']);
/* const userWithEverything: {
    id: number;
    purchases: Purchase[];
    friends: Friend[];
    friendsOfFriends: Friend[];
} */
```

[Playground link to this code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.7.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoFcoIBZwM4oDeAsAFDIXJjagDmAXMnmFHQNxkC+ZoksiKAGKsIIACbIS5SmPQBbAEbRGIeUqgdS3Uj3DR4SZAFUCUSWUrJgYlWugXKAB0w58EPAH5GGLLgIBtAF0HChgRcU9GYWBRMSCQ5DCYiIB5GGjYyOQM8XitMl0+AxQAaQgATwBZOEdzaQpnXzc8RgAiRtcCPFaAGgSQCDAAdwB7KABrNqTM1uQAH2RW6dT08LFurgLSMHLHFAAlCABHdGAoCDEy8rwAHgAVAD5kAF5JZH8SqxBkcYqRmGQd0CAFovJJOMgIAAPSARNDABDje49ZAlJ4eZADABu0GQjE+nH8v3K-0BgU0ZB2e2MpjuuwgN0+0Nh6x+fwBV2qjiezwSqARSJM0BRhxOZwuV1uQqgDyeADJ4YibqLTucxDdpQ8UZyah9Ak9mZkEqAYLiUsgMYR3qgvmySQCUoFGCl-KhAsgISoIDiNFsxBAEAAbODnRLoEAIMDAEbfWiDaWMyEwzJ20k67kACmJLVRQQAlIxpXS9oyHhSdKQEDHmMh0KYXsg42BpRn85oAPQAKmQVZANbryjqlmstkU0E0EM77a2vf7pgA6sBqD5Ou4G02W-4AOQdPzuLeBPMd7uzsC1hdL7Arvc5qTDmyYuy++rIXfNbwuPdBCfIKcWMinue0CLtQABygyjBM67xqYrZbgMwxjOMB5HmQXY9tWZ4DlAIHYOBiETIwd6UCOj5js+ljLOsURrN+CRUXgaQ5NR2S0eSXC-tOFaAdhuEAKI+uU1B0NBzawdub5dFuKLwRBSEoceGF9lhF7UAJ0BCTQIAMEOJEPqo5GaJYknuB+TQBOxL4MTRyRxJZlFrIxqy2TmzF0VonFkEAA)

---

Whichever way you want to go, or some other way, is up to you.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!